# How to Calculate Output from Conv2D and Conv2DTranspose

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

Regarding a question about calculating parameter numbers, I have the follow-up questions.
[Keras CNN model parameters calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44608552/keras-cnn-model-parameters-calculation/56511356#56511356)

Regarding the formula for total parameters, does it mean that, for each input channel, there are 64 sets of learnable weights (filters) but only 1 common bias applied to it, then one single output channel is generated in such a way that 64 filtered results are simply added up followed by adding the common bias?